# Tag "a" esta ignorando o estilo css da imagem

Tags: html, css

Encontrei um problema que ocorre sempre que tento botar um redirecionador de link em uma imagem. Acontece que os atributos do css tipo scale, :hover e etc, funcionam normalmente, mas o tamanho da imagem muda. Isso ocorre sempre que boto um `<a href="">` ou um `<Link/>` do reactJs.
Ja procurei em varios sites e encontrei nada falando sobre isso, inicialmente pensei que poderia ser algum erro do ReactJS com o `<Link/>`, mas verificando, possivelmente pode ser erro de entendimento meu no CSS.

[image: Como fica a imagem quando eu boto a ou <>]
**Como fica a imagem quando eu boto a `<a href>` ou `<Link/>`.**

[image: Como deveria ficar]
**Como deveria ficar.**

Codigo fonte do site: https://github.com/ThiagoCComelli/HTML-CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim que você adiciona o `a`, a propriedade `height: 100%` começa a se referir ao tamanho do `a`, que não possui tamanho definido. Logo, o que recomendo você fazer é definir o tamanho da imagem antes, ou criar uma div para separar a imagem, definindo o tamanho da div antes.